# How can i change the height width of svg in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuetify.js

I am a php developer and i am just learning vue. I want to know how can i change the height width of svg image using `v-img` tag.

Here is the code

```
  <v-img src="/empty.svg" aspect-ratio="2"></v-img>
```

The above code hide the image or doesn't seem to be working.
Please help me to solve this small issue.

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aspect-ratio` doesn't change the height/width of the image, but the whole ratio.

If you want to change height or width, use the `height` and `width` props of `v-img`.

```
<v-img src="/empty.svg" width="500" height="100" />
```

You can specify only one of these props, and add a desired `aspect-ratio` to keep the right ratio. Use `contain="true"` to avoid content crop.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/

Comment: I try this, but this will crop the image

Comment: To avoid cropping, you need to apply `contain` to your v-img. This will set the CSS `object-fit: contain`

Comment: btw you can omit the ="true" on contain (and any other boolean values). Just saying `<v-img contain />` works just as fine